# Pandas - minimum value in 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hi I'm trying to make a chart from 'Category' 'item' and 'Calories'.
I'm trying to get the items that have the minimum calories in each category and make a bar chart with them as category and items on the x-as and calories on the y=as

this is what I'm trying.

[1]  df[["Category", "Item", "Calories"]].groupby("Category").min()

[2]  cicmin = df[["Category", "Item", "Calories"]].groupby("Category").min()
cicmin.plot.bar()

[this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWxSs.png)

[this is what I should get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTqpa.png)

[This is what I want to see on the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWkUU.png)

for some reason I don't see the Items on the x-as as well.
Can anyone help me or point out my mistakes.

I would appreciate it

Comment: do you not want to use `matplotlib`?

Comment: I did import it I thought I was using it. TT__TT

Comment: you can generate plots with specific instructions if you use `plt.plot()` and similar functions.

Comment: Can I ask how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

After the groupby in your 3rd image the DataFrame index is `Category`. This forms the axis when you plot. As I understand it you want to have the index combining `Category` and `Item` for the purposes of plotting. So try reforming the index before the plot function:

```
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x + ' ' + 'Item')
```